# How to immediately change the background image after option has been hovered?

Tags: javascript, html, function, hover, background-image

I'm having a serious problem with hovering over select option in html. When I try to hover over the second select option it's suppose to bring up a background image of a $500 bill immediately, but instead it shows nothing. When I select that option, still nothing happens until I go in select option again and select it again, it comes up. Then I noticed hovering over $1000 select option with the $500 in the background does nothing. When I select $1000 and go back in hovering over $500 will bring up the $1000 image. For a visual example of what I mean, it's here in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8RdPX/1/

**JavaScript CODE:**

```
var bg = this.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
// function to dynamically change the background image when user hovers over an option in select menu
function changeBackgroundImage (bg) {
  if (budList == 1) { //if budList selected index is 1
    bg = this.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/500_USD_note%3B_series_of_1934%3B_obverse.jpg')";
  }
  if (budList == 2) { //if budList selected is 2
    bg = this.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/1000_USD_note%3B_series_of_1934%3B_obverse.jpg')";
  }
}
```

I want to resolve this by immediately taking effect of background image once the said option is hovered, then when that is selected, enter select option again and if hovered over another option to change it. I'm just using these two as examples, as I add more, I want it to efficiently change images as each option is hovered over. Thanks!

I tried with CSS :hover selector property but doesn't seem to be working for the html background image, only the option's background image:

**HTML**

```
<form>
<!--show a large print of green font color and size money-->
    Select your DSLR budget range:
    <select id="budgetSel" onChange="onChange();">
        <option value="selectOneBudget" selected="selected">Select one</option>
        <option id="test500" value="fiveHundredDollars" onMouseOver="changeBackgroundImage(this);">&lt; $500</option>
        <option id="test1000" value="thousandDollars" onMouseOver="changeBackgroundImage(this);">&lt; $1000</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#test500:hover{
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/500_USD_note%3B_series_of_1934%3B_obverse.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
#test1000:hover{
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/1000_USD_note%3B_series_of_1934%3B_obverse.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Comment: I forget, isn't it possible to use a `:hover` selector directly in CSS?

Comment: yes, but can achieve the same effect in javascript too. I am required to use javascript anyway.

Comment: You are saying that you are required to use Javascript for this specific function?  Or just in general for the assignment?

Comment: no, the professor says jquery is too easy and have to understand javascript first before using any of that. I updated with the CSS solution, to no avail, doesn't work.

Comment: `option` elements don't have a `:hover` event or psuedo class. Here is a simplified implementation of the `select.onchange` using pure Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/7Z67r/1

Comment: Okay, how about when option is being hovered to change the image because it does work. I hovered over option a second time and it changed the background, so hover does support this property.

Comment: The only browser I can get this to work in is Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/7Z67r/2/ So if you're in Firefox, you can do that. Note, if you need to support older versions of IE, you'll need to use `event.attachEvent()` instead of `event.eventListener()`, which has a slightly different syntax as well.